Having device play a custom sound when sending FCM message through Firebase console
How can I send a custom sound through the Firebase Cloud Messaging console?
I see the docs say to add sound key to payload and I also see that someone else asked this here and that was the answer.
I was able to send a custom sound through postman, but it doesn’t work for me with the firebase console.
